# Save custom attributes of product in woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I have some custom attributes for each product in woocommerce, I can edit them at the Attributes tab. I can also read them using this code

```
$product = new WC_Product($product_id);
$v = $product->get_attribute('myattr_name');
```

But I don't understand how to set this attribute value. Googling not helps. Do you know? I am looking for something like this

```
$product->set_attribute('myattr_name', $new_value);
```

But as I can see, there is no such method.

Comment: it's a simple or a variable product ?

Comment: @mmm A simple one

Comment: try with that : `$product->set_props(["attributes" => ["myattr_name" => $new_value]]); $product->save();`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it working with next code:

```
$product = wc_get_product($productId);
$attrName = 'my_attribute';
$attrValue = 'some value'

$attr = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attr->set_name( $attrName );
$attr->set_options( [$attrValue] );
$attr->set_visible(1);
$attr->set_variation(1);
$attr->set_position(0);
$attr->set_id( 0 );
$attrs[$attrName] = $attr;
$product->set_attributes($attrs);
$product->save();
```